# Trigger problems when it comes to Supertypes in SQL/DBeaver

Tags: sql, triggers, dbeaver, subtype

Hello Stackoverflowers!

I am new to SQL/DataOracleModeler and i came to the point where I cannot move on anymore.

To explain:

I have a table 'Vehicles' as Supertype and 'Segways' 'Bycicle' and 'Cars' as Subtypes.

I added a discriminator for them (S for segways, F for Fahhrad, A for Auto (german translation))

My problem now is:

Dbeaver doesnt like my triggers.

First a picture to show you better:
[Model of my Super/Sub-types](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQRZ8.png)

Here is one of the triggers:

```
  INSERT OR
  UPDATE OF Inventar_ID ON Segway FOR EACH ROW DECLARE d CHAR (8);
  BEGIN
    SELECT A.FahrzeugArt_FahrzeugArt
    INTO d
    FROM Fahrzeug A
    WHERE A.Inventar_ID = :new.Inventar_ID;
    IF (d              IS NULL OR d <> 'S') THEN
      raise_application_error(-20223,'FK Segway_Fahrzeug_FK in Table Segway violates Arc constraint on Table Fahrzeug - discriminator column FahrzeugArt_FahrzeugArt doesn''t have value ''S''');
    END IF;
  EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    NULL;
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    RAISE;
  END;
  /
```

But when i start the SQL, on this point it asks me to bind param? First of all, why?

And the real problem is. I cannot just say:

```
INSERT INTO AUTO VALUES (blablabla)
```

Because he says:
parent key not found.

No Problem - I can create a Parent "Vehicle" with ID 1 and then say **INSERT INTO AUTO (ID1,...)**
But when i **SELECT ID1** i get a table where all columns are twice. The first ones are all NULL values and the second ones are filled with the statement INSERT INTO AUTO (ID1,...)

But the goal of Super/Subtypes shouldnt be like this?

I am really frustrating, and cannot really lookup on the internet anymore as we work with Data Oracle Modeler and DBeaver and theres not much to find.

And now i am asking you, **what AM I missing here?**

And yes i checked the forum but I didn't really find a similar question here.
I hope anyone can help and I am sorry for disturbing. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to model super/subtypes but what you've done is not one of them. If you are going to physicalise the supertype then it should contain all the common columns and then the subtypes will only contain the columns specific to each subtype - you appear to have duplicated them all.

Anyway, with the type of model you have, for each "logical" record you have, first you would need to insert the supertype record and then you would need to insert the subtype record.

What is the purpose of your triggers? Presumably you have all the data needed to insert both types of record so why not just use insert statements?

Comment: Hello Nick, thank you for this comment.
I know the attributes of the Supertype looks long but are not the same as in the subtypes. 
They all have many same attributes and just some different.

The supertype should be abstract. It shouldnt even be able to make a new "Vehicle" . It should only be possible to create new Segways, Cars or Bycicles..

And what i assume the trigger should do is, if i say Vehicle_Art = 'S' that it should detect its an Segway...
I hope this helped you more to understand my problem and thank you for your answer!

Comment: When you physicalise a logical super/subtype model you either create a parent table with the common columns and child tables for the subtype-specific columns or you don't create a parent table and include all the common columns in each of the subtype-specific tables. Which approach are you trying to take - as your solution doesn't really look like either at the moment?

Comment: I am sorry - So i actually want to insert a new Segway without creating any new 'Vehicle'. But it doesn't allow me to as parent key is missing.

Comment: Precisely! Your design requires a Segway record and a corresponding parent vehicle record (1:1 relationship). If this is what you want then it is a perfectly acceptable design pattern (though not the way you've implemented it). However, if you don't want the parent vehicle table and just have the vehicle type tables then that is also an acceptable design pattern - you just need to denormalise all the common columns held at the vehicle level into each vehicle type table